# perform operation on return value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return measurement data from a database. Unfortunatly the data is in a different quantity (kWatt, I need Watt) and want to do the transformation preferably in the SQL statement

So I want to multiple the measuremententry with 1000 in

> SELECT measuremententry FROM log

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT measuremententry * 1000 AS measuremententry 
  FROM log
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
SELECT kilowatts * 1000 as watts FROM log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT measuremententry * 1000 FROM log
```

Works for me in PostGre, should work for you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
SELECT measuremententry * 1000 FROM log
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT measuremententry*1000 as measuremententry FROM log